# Robotframework: Variable ${CUSTOM_VARIABLE} not found

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I created a robotframework testcase which seems to be working if I hardcopy the xpath directly into the keywords.

For example:

```
*** Variables ***
${MAIN_FOLDER}=//span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]

*** Keywords ***
Folder tear down
    navigate to process designer
    wait until element is visible  ${FRAME}  180s
    select frame  ${FRAME}
    #finds the created folder
    wait until element is visible  xpath=//span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]
    click element  xpath=//span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]
    #below it is basically the same xpath as the one above. The above one works, the below one does not
    open context menu  ${MAIN_FOLDER}
    #press on delete
    wait until element is visible  xpath=//li[a[contains(@data-selected-option, "DELETE")]]  10s
    click element  xpath=//li[a[contains(@data-selected-option, "DELETE")]]
    #confirm delete
    wait until element is visible  xpath=//button[contains(@class, "btn-modal btn-modal-primary hide-focus")]
    click element  xpath=//button[contains(@class, "btn-modal btn-modal-primary hide-focus")]
```

Why is it not working with custom variables? It is literally the same xpath

Answer (score 0):

It's not how we use variables in robotframework.

Try this:

`${MAIN_FOLDER}    //span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]`

or

`${MAIN_FOLDER}=  Set Variable   //span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]`

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
*** Variables ***
${MAIN_FOLDER}=//span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]
```

You've defined a variable literally named `${MAIN_FOLDER}=//span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]` with a null value.

You need to have two or more spaces after a variable name (and optional `=`):

```
${MAIN_FOLDER}=    //span[text()=" AutomationTestFolder "]
```